why my Adaptive card giving error 401 on outlook button click
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0",
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Http",
            "title": "Approve",
            "id": "btnApprove",
            "url": "https://prod2-12.centralindia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/a79361c76b21450e883485e81712ca4e/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01",
            "method": "POST",
            "body": "{\"Remarks\":\"{{Remarkstxt.text}}\"\n\"Status\":\"Approved\"\n}",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "Authorization",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Content-type",
                    "value": "application/json"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.Http",
            "title": "Reject",
            "id": "btnRejected",
            "url": "https://prod2-12.centralindia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/a79361c76b21450e883485e81712ca4e/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01",
            "method": "POST",
            "body": "{\"Remarks\":\"{{Remarkstxt.text}}\"\n\"Status\":\"Rejected\"\n}",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "Authorization",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Content-type",
                    "value": "application/json"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "Remarks",
            "id": "Remarkstxt",
            "isMultiline": true
        }
    ]
}

When I click on Adaptive card button it is giving 401 error

You can’t just call a logic app without the signature on the url. That’s the first thing. Second thing, where is the adaptive card coming from? If it’s LA or PA, you’re best to catch the reply there, not directly invoke another flow from the button push.
